# How to refine the precision of some Matlab simulations

Tags: matlab, simulation

I have to evaluate the following expectation, where

- `U_1,...,U_6` are real numbers
- `U_6`=0
- `epsilon_1,...,epsilon_6` are i.i.d. [Gumbel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution).

[image]

By the properties of the Gumbel distribution the expectation above is

[image]

In Matlab I try to compute the expectation using the close form and by simulation. I get results that are quite different. Could you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong or how to improve the precision of my simulations?

```
clear
rng default

U=[0.474986974509930,0.817638395934678,-0.369150759886231,-2.48005242841836,-2.73055549762839,0];

%Close form
A1=log(sum(exp(U))+1);

%Simulation
r=10^6; %number of simulations to evaluate expectation of the max
epsilon=-evrnd(0,1,r,6); 
A2=mean(max(epsilon+U,[],2));
```

I get `A1=1.9`, `A2=2.3`.

---

Even if I try to repeat the simulation many times and average across them, the result does not seem to improve.

```
T=10^3;
A2=zeros(T,1);
for t=1:10^3
r=10^5; %number of simulations to evaluate expectation of the max
epsilon=-evrnd(0,1,r,6); 
A2(t)=mean(max(epsilon+U,[],2)); 
end
A2=mean(A2);
```

Comment: Is this the output you get when you print the variable in the console or is the value in the work space the same? (with `format long` you can increase the precision for console output)

Comment: thanks. They are the same, I have just reported the first digit after the comma.

Comment: Are you sure about the theoretical expression for the expectation? Can you give any reference from which it was obtained?

Comment: Based on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/192424/28285) (I have only skimmed over it), the theoretical result seems to be `log(sum(exp(U))) + .5772`, which is in agreement with the simulations